# Display two frames of the same class with Python and Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote a simple game in Python. Now I'm trying to give it a GUI (currently it is text based). Since there aren't moving objects, I decieded to use Tkinter (I like the grid arrangement, the east coding to get a menu and the fact that there is no need to install anything).

I have a few problems I can't seem to solve:

1. I want two display two game boards on the screen. I created a frame class that contain the information and displays it, but it only shows the first one. The second is created but does not appear on screen.
2. All the tiles on the board has the same functionality, but when I press a tile (label object) I want to use some metadata of the object. That is, I want to assign it a string and when I press it I want to get the string attached to the label I pressed. I can't figure out how to do it. 
   **--- Solved in the comments by Eric Levieil**
3. (least important) Can I put two images, one on top of the other without using canvas/absolute position?

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class GameBoard(ttk.Frame):
    tiles = []
    def __init__(self, parent, temp, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.graphics = {'1H':tk.PhotoImage(file='graphics/1H.gif'),
                '0': tk.PhotoImage(file='graphics/0.gif')}

        for row_num in range(5):
            row = []
            for cell_num in range(10):
                row.append(ttk.Label(self))
                row[cell_num]['image'] = self.graphics[temp]
                row[cell_num].bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: print('(%d,%d)'%(row_num,cell_num)))
            self.tiles.append(row)

        for row_num in range(5):
            for cell_num in range(10):
                self.tiles[row_num][cell_num].grid(row=row_num, column=cell_num)


class MainBoard(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        player_1_name = ttk.Label(self, text='Player 1').grid(row=0, sticky=tk.W)
        player_1_board = GameBoard(self, '0')
        player_1_board.grid(row=1, sticky=(tk.N, tk.W))       
        player_2_name = ttk.Label(self, text='Player 2').grid(row=2, sticky=tk.W)
        player_2_board = GameBoard(self, '1H')
        player_2_board.grid(row=3, sticky=(tk.S, tk.W))
        self.grid(row=0)



def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Battleship')
    MainBoard(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks,
Uri

Edit: Here are the two images I'm using [graphics.zip](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~urigrupe/graphics.zip).

Comment: I think the problem is because of the pictures you are using. Probably their size, but this is just an idea.

Comment: Your second problem is a classic one. `lambda event: print('(%d,%d)'%(row_num,cell_num)` -> `lambda event, r= row_num, c = cell_num: print('(%d,%d)'%(r,c)`

Comment: Thanks @EricLevieil! That solves the second one.

Comment: @Axl, since I don't specify sizes the window should just grow. This is what happens with other objects I add. Thanks

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provide those two images you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed it. Reinitialize your tiles in `GameBoard.__init__` and it will do.

Just before your first `for-Loop`:

`self.tiles=[]`

`for row_num in range(5):`

Comment: That worked! Why is the original way I wrote it was wrong? When the tiles variable was different or every player. Anyway thanks.

Comment: Hi Uri, the tiles variable is declared for the class  (directly below class declaration) and seems to be not automatically initialised for every single instance.

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem is in how you are defining `tiles`. Because you are initializing it outsize of `__init__`, the same `tiles` is shared among all instances of this class. If you create two instances and modify the variable in the second instance, it will affect the first instance (and visa versa)

Since you want each instance to have its own list of tiles, you should initialize it inside `__init__`:

```
class GameBoard(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, temp, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.tiles = []
        ...
```

As for the problem with assigning values to buttons, for that you can use `lambda` or ``functools.partial`, and you need to create a closure such at the values are bound to each instance:

```
row[cell_num].bind('<Button-1>', lambda event, row=row_num, cell=cell_num: print('(%d,%d)'%(row,cell)))
```

The third question about whether you can stack images on top of each other is a bit vague. It really depends on the effect that you want. You can certainly place two images in the same grid cell with `grid`, or on top of each other with `place`. Whether that gives you the visual effect you want, I don't know.

Comment: `tiles` is shared about all __instances__ of type `GameBoard` not shared among all __classes__ or am I getting something wrong here?

Comment: @R4PH43L: it is shared by all instances of that class.  I'll fix my answer. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Thanks, I now understand the difference between the two definitions. As for the other part, I thought about adding a picture with transparent background, but instead I created a combined image file.